# WCF calling a script writing on a second server

Tags: wcf, batch-file

I'm trying to call a batch file from a WCF service.  The WCF and the batch file are both located on the same server (lets call it serverA), but the batch file must perform tasks on another server (serverB).

I have simplified the batch file as much as possible.  For now, here is the code :

```
MD "\\serveurB\intermediateDirectory\foo"
COPY "C:\TEMP\myFile.CSV" "\\serverB\intermediateDirectory\foo\myFile.CSV"
MD "C:\TEMP\bar"
```

When I execute the batch file directly, everything works fine.  But when I call it through the WCF, the fist two operations (those linked to serverB) are not executed.  The last task is completed : I have my new "bar" directory on serverA, but nothing on serverB.

Within the WCF, the batch file is call with a simple Process.Start(exePath).

I have given full read/write/modify rights to everyone on the \\serverB\intermediateDirectory folder, but it does not seem to help.

Any clue on how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its most likely related to the permissions of the user account that the WCF service is running under. You'll need the account (set in IIS application pool) to be a network user with the right permissions to execute the batch file and have the right access to the network resources

Comment: That did the job.  I set the Identity parameter in the IIS  application pool to use an account that has administrator rights on both servers, and it worked.  Thank you very much for your quick answer!